# BokehJS Title Text Alignment

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am developing with the BokehJS library and need some help since the documentation for the JS side of the library is pretty thin.

In python you can change the text alignment via the following command,

```
p = figure(title='Title',plot_width=500, plot_height=200, tools='')
p.title.text_align = 'center'
```

In JS there is no comparable attribute.

```
var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;
var p = plt.figure({ title: "Title",height: 300,width: 300,tools: ''});
p.title.<???>
```

I believe the anchor function is responsible for setting the alignment but I need help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the solution through navigating the attributes in the chrome developer tools.

```
var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;
var p = plt.figure({ title: "Title",height: 300,width: 300,tools: ''});
p.attributes["above"][0]['align']='center';
```

The code above centers the title text as I desired. In the case above, the plot attribute in the "above" position is the Title.

Answer (score 7):

There is a strict 1-1 correspondence maintained between the Python Bokeh models, and the corresponding BokehJS models (this is maintained under test). So the [Python Reference Guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference.html) is not a terrible reference for BokehJS as well.

However, in this particular case, it's not `text_align` that want. Instead you should use:

```
p.title.align = 'center'
```

The uninteresting reason is that `text_align` has a specific meaning to the HTML canvas, that does not really correspond well to aligning titles.

---

As an aside, BokehJS used to be purely a hidden implementation detail, which is why the docs for it are thin. We are definitely interested in developing it better as a standalone JS library, including improving the documentation, but that takes people-time, which is currently spread very thin. If you'd be interested in helping improve BokehJS please reach out on [GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) or the [Discourse](https://discourse.bokeh.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment.  I am getting the following results on the develop tools console on chrome. var p = plt.figure(...), typeof p21.title -> "string". Am I missing something. I ma using the pydata CDN for Bokeh 0.12.6 (The JS library and the api library).

Comment: Also I would love to help but my JS experience is limited to a month currently.

Comment: Sorry I can't tell form context what your issue is that you are describing. SO is not so good for iterative back and forth type help. Maybe you can come by the mailing list? https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh I can also ping another core dev there that is better suited to answer BokehJS API questions